# UITableViewController does not automatically resizes and repositions its table view when there is in-line editing of text fields

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, ios7, uitableview

**UPDATE** (SOLVED ALREADY) :)
I tried to recreate my scene from scratch.  And I found out that if the Class of the table view controller is "UITableViewController", the repositioning of view when keyboard appears happens properly.  But when I set the Class of the table view controller to my custom class, the repositioning doesn't happen.  Why is this so?  Given that my custom class is a subclass of UITableViewController and nowhere in my implementation did I implement any data source and data delegate since I am using static cells?

I forgot to add the delegate in my interface declaration.  Now it's working already.

```
@interface CustomClass : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
```

---

I have a UITableViewController where the tableview content is static cells and style is plain.  I added 7 table view cells.  In each cell, I added a text field.

When I click on a table view cell, the keyboard shows but the table view did not reposition; thus hiding the table view cell that I selected.

I have solved this before but I was using a view controller then which I embedded inside a scrollview.  But seeing from documentation, UITableViewController, which has a scrollview by default, is supposed to automatically resize and reposition it's table view.

I am working on XCode 5 and using iOS 7 latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough checking, I realised, my custom class only subclass UITableViewController without adding the delegate :(

below solves the problem... at last! :)

```
@interface CustomClass : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the offset (y) of the tableView whenever textField's action is didBeginEditing.

If you need any more help let me know ;D

Comment: i tried to set the offset but a black area appeared in the bottom behind the keyboard and the tableview didn't scroll up at all.  i pasted the code i used.  Sorry but i am not that good in the UI so it might be wrong at all.
Would appreciate if you have a sample code in both begin and end editing method

Answer (score 0):

It should automatically change its size, but not necessarily adjust its position/offset.

Are you sure the table view still covers the entire screen, even *below* the keyboard?
You can check this by scrolling and looking at the scrollbars.

If you want to adjust the content offset, do so in the callback when the user begins editing the text field.

Comment: i tried to set the offset but a black area appeared in the bottom behind the keyboard and the tableview didn't scroll up at all. i pasted the code i used. Sorry but i am not that good in the UI so it might be wrong at all.
Would appreciate if you have a sample code in both begin and end editing method

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the code that sets the content offset of the table view.

The table cell for text field with the first responder status should automatically scroll above the keyboard. You shouldn't have to write a lick of code for this.

If you are using static cells, make sure that your table view controller does not implement the table view data source methods. Also, the view controller that you dragged onto the IB canvas must be a UITableViewController; it can't be a UIViewController that contains a UITableView dragged from the objects library.

Comment: i already removed that code.  i know that i should not even put that code since i am using uitableviewcontroller... however please see my UPDATE of the question on what I have discovered.  Need your advise. thanks.